# Error Message: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I execute the code shown later, I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

From my understanding I am not using a set operation (like `COUNT`, `SUM`).

Does anyone have a clue where this error message comes from?

```sql
SELECT 
    base.*,
    0.5 * (base.Adjustment / 1 - base.Adjustment) * dur.[MD_PP] * base.URC_CP_disc AS CDA_PP_1
FROM 
    [dbo].[_Result_calculation] base
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[MDC_Calc] dur ON dur.[TID] = base.[TID]
                         AND dur.[UWY] = base.[UWY]
                         AND dur.[TXG] = base.[TXG]
                         AND dur.Label = base.Label
                         AND dur.Label_EP = base.Label_EP
                         AND dur.[Quarter] = base.[Quarter];
```

Comment: Somewhere, you are comparing or using both an `nvarchar` to a `float` in an expression, without explicit conversion, and the value in the `nvarchar` isn't a valid `float` value. We don't know *where* that's happening as we don't have a copy of your database, DDL and DML nor access to your instance. Take the time to post a full [mre] so we know where the comparison is. Or, just take the time to check your data types.

Comment: "NULL value is eliminated" is only a warning. The conversion error is, well, an error. I assume the latter is the actual problem. Either `_Result_calculation` or `MDC_Calc` may actually be a view that does include an aggregate (and may or may not be the source of conversion issues itself).

Comment: Also, the message *"Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."* isn't an error, it's a warning, as it *literally* tells you. What makes less sense with that warning is that it appears you have *no* aggregate functions in the statement, and it doesn't look like you reference any UDFs, so that warning seems to have little to do with the above.

Comment: You should paste the table _Result_calculation definition. That would be useful to detect the field that is trying a invalid cast.

Comment: Comment out the last calculated column in your select list and run the query. If it error  happens then it is related to your joins and the table / view definitions. If not, the the error is related to your calculated expression and the columns it uses.  And this `(base.Adjustment / 1 - base.Adjustment)` is just lazy coding. Do you expect the division to occur first or the subtraction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. CTL+L to Display Estimated Execution Plan
2. add a TOP 1 (generally it will not crash as the estimated execution plan uses to 10 values)
3. Left click and show Execution Plan as XML
4. the column with faulty data will generally show up in the warnings. <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT( ...
   or down in the xml file with ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float, ...